# Internationalization in flutter not working as expected

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

Here is what I tried.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var countryCode = Localizations.localeOf(context);
    var localization = new MyAppLocalizations(countryCode);
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(),
      body: new Center(
        child:new Text(localization.title),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppLocalizations {
  MyAppLocalizations(this.locale);
  final Locale locale;
  static MyAppLocalizations of(BuildContext context) {
  return Localizations.of<MyAppLocalizations>(context, 
  MyAppLocalizations);
  }

  static Map<String, Map<String, String>> _localizedValues = localeMap();

  String get title {
    return _localizedValues[locale.languageCode]['title'];
  }
}

Map<String, Map<String, String>> localeMap(){
   Map<String, Map<String, String>> _localisedMap ={
    'en': {
      'title': 'Hello World',
    },
    'es': {
      'title': 'Hola Mundo',
    },
  };
  return _localisedMap;
}
```

This is pretty much the same example provided in the flutter documentation.I was trying this on the emulator.I changed the general language settings to Spanish.But, the app still rendered the English title.Also, in the window.dart file, all the language codes are depricated.I am not sure how to achieve the mapping of the region code and country code in this case.
Please help if anybody has any idea regarding the same.

Comment: The deprecated language codes probably have a comment what to use instead, might just be a name change like upper/lowercase to match the style guide.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer - thank you for that.But I changed the language settings of the emulator to Spanish, but still the English text is displayed.Do you have any idea on what I might be missing here?